# Grouping and Sum DataTable Rows without Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have datatable like this

```
Name           Price
product1        10
product1        12
product2        3
product2        5
product2        7
product3        22
```

I would like to group the same named products and sum the prices like this --->

```
Name           Price
product1        10
product1        12
                22

product2        3
product2        5
product2        7
                15

product3        22
                22
```

I should't make it with linq. How can i distinguish the different value of names and sum them like in the table.

Comment: Use a Dictionary<string, int>

Comment: In the future, please include some code in your questions (what you have attempted on your own, what is not working about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get dictionary where the key is name of product, and the value is a Sum of all the same product Prices.

```
var allProducts = context.Products.Where(.....what products you want to take from     db).ToList();

   Dictionary<String, Int32> dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
   foreach(var product in allProducts)
   {
      Int32 value = 0;
      if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(product.Name, out value))
      {
         dictionary.Add(product.Name, product.Price);
         continue;
      }
            value += product.Price;
            dictionary[product.Name] = value;
   }
```

Comment: Having this error = "An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have renewed my code. So you can use it and it will work.